# Python IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to coding and python.

Trying to make a little game and getting this error message:

> IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10.

My question is:
How should I fix this and how to respawn a new ice drop after the first one reached the end?

Thanks for your time and help.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import random

WIDTH = 20
HEIGHT = 10

player_position = 0
ice_position = [0, random.randint(0, WIDTH - 1)]

while True:
    #init world
    arr = np.zeros((HEIGHT, WIDTH)).astype(np.uint8)
    #populate player
    arr[-1, player_position] = 255
    #populate ice
    arr[ice_position[0], ice_position[1]] = 100
    #show world
    arr = cv2.resize(arr, (WIDTH * 50, HEIGHT * 50), interpolation = 
    cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    
    cv2.imshow("game", arr)  #show image
    k = cv2.waitKey(100) # wait for 100ms
    
    # make the ice fall
    ice_position[0] += 1
    
    
    
    # player action
    if k == ord("d"):
       if player_position < WIDTH - 1:
          player_position += 1
    
       if k == ord("a"):
          if player_position > 0:
             player_position -= 1
       
       
       if k == ord("q"):
            exit()
```

Comment: The indexes are 0-9 inclusive.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for replying. I understand the indexes are from 0 to 9. but I don't know where and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use opencv for games, use pygame or similar. Anyway, here is the solution -

```
...
if ice_position[0] !=10:
    arr[ice_position[0], ice_position[1]] = 100
else:
    ice_position[0]=0
...
```

you just needed to add an if else statement to reset to 0 when the snowball reached the end

Comment: Haha, it worked, thanks :D